# 301 redirect old link to new sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, magento-1.6

I am trying to do a redirect in my Joomla .htaccess file
The incorrect link is:

```
http://nilandsplace.com/index.php/camping_eng/camping?___store=camping_eng
```

I am trying to get it to go to:

```
http://nilandsplace.com/store/index.php/camping/camping-home/?___store=camping
```

No mater what 301 redirect I have tried it does not work I get a 404 page not found or I get a 500 server error. It also could just go to:

```
http://nilandsplace.com/store/camping/
```

I almost got it to work by getting rid of the index.php in the link, but there are a lot of old external links in that have it with the index.php. I have tried more then 15 different ways and still can't get it without destroying my Joomla link

```
http://nilandsplace.com/index.php
```

I know the basics, the rewrite engine is on and I have been putting everything before the Joomla redirects that are many. The Joomla .htaccess is the basic one that comes with Joomla install.
Thanks James Niland
http://nilandsplace.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /camping_eng/camping\?___store=camping_eng [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/camping/? [R=301,L]
```